# Scrapy : How to write a HttpProxyMiddleware?

Tags: scrapy

The docs of `Scrapy` says about `HttpProxyMiddleware` is like this:

> This middleware sets the HTTP `proxy` to use for requests, by setting the `proxy` meta value for `Request` objects.
>
> Like the Python standard library modules `urllib` and `urllib2`, it obeys the following environment variables:
>
> ```
> http_proxy
> https_proxy
> no_proxy
> ```
>
> You can also set the meta key proxy per-request, to a value like `http://some_proxy_server:port` or `http://username:password@some_proxy_server:port`. Keep in mind this value will take precedence over `http_proxy/https_proxy` environment variables, and it will also ignore `no_proxy` environment variable.

docs:https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=Proxy#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy

But there are no examples in the docs.
I have no ideas how to write a `HttpProxyMiddleware`.
Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `settings.py` just do this.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 100
}
```

And then while `yield`ing each request do this

```
yield Request(meta={'proxy': "http://%s"%(random.choice(["IP:PORT", "IP:PORT"]))})
```

That's it!

Comment: Assuming I already have 5 proxy IP address. I want to set a  pool of IP address,what should I do?

Comment: @zwl1619 create LIST of IPs in your Spider file, and use a random proxy IP with each request ...

Comment: Could you show me the code please? I don't know how to make it random.

Comment: Where do we yield this Request, in which file?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write one. **HttpProxyMiddleware** already exists in Scrapy.

As docs state, there are two ways of letting Scrapy know you need your requests to go through a proxy:

1. Setting environment variables
   (e.g. from the command line)

   ```
   export http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port"
   ```
2. You can also set the meta key **"proxy"** per-request, to a value like http://some_proxy_server:port or http://username:password@some_proxy_server:port.

   > Keep in mind this value will take precedence over **http_proxy**/**https_proxy** environment variables, and it will also ignore **no_proxy** environment variable

   e.g.

   ```
   yield Request("http://google.com", meta={'proxy':'http://username:password@some_proxy_server:port'}, callback=self.some_method)
   ```

Comment: Assuming I already have 5 proxy IP address. I want to set a  pool of IP address,what should I do?